# Repeated tag wiki edits only adding chat room links

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

Just been going through some edits, and there seems to be a lot from a single person where the only edit is just adding a chat room edit... This must be the 10th at least I've seen https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1301052 - what action should be taken on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I approved a few of those, they seem fine to me.  It just seems like they realized it was a good idea and decided to implement it.  It's seems good to have someone doing it, as long as they don't add them to the excerpts, and as long as there is a dedicated SE chat room for it.

Comment: That was my impression - so I also approved a couple... but then there's rooms that aren't dedicated rooms (unless the editor/owner intends to make them so)

Comment: @JonClements, well that would be different then, seems like that would just lead to dead links.

Comment: So yeah, hence the question - adding chatrooms to a wiki is fine by me - as long as it's there... suddenly adding 24 of them seems a bit odd...

Comment: yeh, it seemed a bit odd.